# Gibt es Steigerungsformen für falsch und richtig?

Tags: adjective, comparison

Eigentlich war ich immer der Meinung, dass jedes Adjektiv über eine Steigerungsform verfügt.
Auch wenn bei einigen der Wortstamm wechselt.

> gut, besser, am besten

Gibt es auch Steigerungsformen für falsch und richtig, oder ist es ganz einfach entweder falsch oder richtig?

Welche (andern) Adjektive ohne Steigerungsformen gibt es?

Comment: Steigerungsformen für falsch und richtig sind falsch. :)

Comment: @user unknown. Laut meinem Sprachgefühl ist so auch nicht ganz richtig.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Für "[falsch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/falsch)" lässt sich die Frage eindeutig beantworten. Laut Duden ist die Steigerungsform:

> falsch, falscher, falscheste

Für "[richtig](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/richtig_fehlerfrei_passend_wahr)" wird's richtig lustig. Laut Duden gibt es keine Steigerungsform. Jedenfalls ist keine aufgeführt, was sonst bei Adjektiven der Fall ist. Aber im Duden ist gelistet:

> es wäre das Richtigste, wenn …; aber es wäre am richtigsten, wenn …

Das heißt, es gibt einen Superlativ. Was auf eine Steigerungsform schließen lässt, aber nicht zwingend. Es könnte durch aus sein, daß es diese Ausdrücke nur in den Duden geschafft haben, weil sie oft verwendet werden (Sprache lebt), nicht weil sie ursprünglich grammatisch korrekt waren.

Das heisst also, der Satz, den Du gerade ließt, wäre richtiger, wenn ich "liest" geschrieben hätte. Dann wär nämlich nur noch "heisst" falsch. Oh, warte, Du bist Schweizer ... ;)

Daher: "falsch" darfst Du richtig steigern; ob Du "richtig" falsch steigern willst oder gar nicht, überlasse ich Dir :)

Comment: Syntaktisch mag das stimmen, semantisch trifft das jedenfalls nicht überall zu. Aber das ist mir zu egal, um mich darüber trefflich zu streiten. Ich würde auch eher von absolut richtig oder völlig falsch sprechen, als von falschesten oder richtigsten. Beispiel eine Antwort auf einem Führerscheinfragebogen ist richtig oder falsch, da gibt es weiter nichts.

Comment: Ich hoffe, Du nimmst die letzten beiden Absätze nicht zu ernst, @bernd_k.

Answer (score 7):

Es gibt Adjektive, die von ihrer Meinung her keine Steigerungsformen besitzen sollten:

> Einzig, allmächtig, leer, nichtig, perfekt, ewig, ...

Trotzdem werden manche doch gesteigert, weil man nicht  die buchstäbliche Bedeutung im Auge hat oder weil mein kein Logiker ist...

Man kann auch absichtlich einen stilistischen Effekt suchen. Das berühmteste Beispiel ist wahrscheinlich Orwell's

> Alle Tiere sind gleich,
>   aber manche sind gleicher.

Answer (score 5):

> Welche (andern) Adjektive ohne Steigerungsformen gibt es?

- schwanger
- blind, taub
- tot
- braunäugig
- zweibeinig

Comment: blauäugig würde ich aus der Aufzählung rausnehmen.

Comment: "tot" wäre hier zu erwähnen, und das absolut schlagende "dreibeinig" (von Wolf Schneider gelernt).

Comment: @perdian: So besser? `:)`

Comment: @Hendrik: Danke! Habs hinzugefügt.

Comment: Zu *schwangerer* hat der Zwiebelfisch auch etwas [zu sagen](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,626770,00.html).

Comment: @musiKk: Schöne Kolumne!

Answer (score 2):

Um den 2. Teil der Frage nach anderen Adjektiven dieser Art zu beantworten:

> egal
>
> relativ

Praktische Verwendung von "relativ" höre man von [Wise Guys - Relativ (Live)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaOHMxJ_-N4)